# flask redirect incorrectly passing a function reference

Tags: python, flask

I'm building a flask app that uses multiple OAuth tokens (stored in DB) that access external API, and want the user to select which token set to apply.  The different tokens have access to different resources.

The code below gets tokens from the DB and displays in a unordered list, containing a href to my tokenSet route with the tokenid.   The href target URL renders correctly in browser.

Intent is when clicked the credentials get updated with the selected token, and user is returned home.  i.e.

- click on http://localhost/xero/tokenSet/sakas837hafhah
- tokenSet route sets credentials to use token sakas837hafhah
- return to http://localhost/xeroHome

However when clicked, the browser redirects but tokenID in the url is replaced with (what appears to be) the object for the function/route its redirecting to.    i.e.

```
http://localhost/xero/tokenSet/<function%20xeroHome%20at%200xb0d3f810>
```

Can anyone please explain why ????  or what i'm missing ??

```
@app.route('/xero/')
def xeroHome():
   data = {"expires_at": str(datetime.fromtimestamp(credentials.token["expires_at"]))}    
   return render_template('xeroHome.html', title='Xero', data=data)


@app.route('/xero/tokens/')
def xeroTokenList():    
    tokens = o2token.query.filter_by(apiname="xero").all()
    tokenList={}
    link = "<ul>"
    for token in tokens:
        tokenList[token.useremail] = token.refresh_token
        link += f"<li><a href='/xero/tokenSet/{token.refresh_token}'>{token.useremail}</a></li>"
    link += "</ul>"
    return link


@app.route('/xero/tokenSet/<selected_token>')
def xeroTokenSet(selected_token):
    token = o2token.query.filter_by(refresh_token=selected_token).first().to_token()
    credentials.token = token
    return redirect(xeroHome)
```

UPDATE:  with some logging, it appears tokenSet is being hit twice when href is clicked ... firstly with the correct tokenID and a second time with the function.  Makes me more confused - but just in case that helps.

Comment: pass value(credentials)  in `return redirect(xeroHome)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
return redirect(xeroHome)
```

with

```
return redirect(url_for('xeroHome'))
```

Of course, you will also need to import url_for from flask

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately that gives an error when it hits the redirect.   TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable.    I dont understand how/why its trying to pass a function.

Comment: @denniseagles My bad, I missed out quotes in my answer. Try it again.